# Removing http key in cachefactory

Tags: angularjs, caching

I am storing all my http calls in the cache by following statement
 $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;

Now I want to remove the particular http call from that cache.

I know that we dont have option to read all the key values. Hence just I need to know what would be the key value of that array .

So that I will remove it via cachefactory.remove(key).

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$httpProvider.defaults.cache` to `true` will create a cache with `$http` as the key. You can get this cache like you get any other cache:

```
var $httpCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
```

once you have the cache you can use it like any other cache:

```
$httpCache.remove(key);
```

More info can be found here:
[$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)
[$cacheFactory.Cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache)

Comment: I want to know what that key value would be. For eg If I made three http get request then my cachefactory would have list of three items. In that I want to remove the second http request from that cache list. For that I need to know the key value of it. So kindly tell me what that key value would be ? I tried by removing it via index but it did not worked

Comment: I also tried to view all the keys in the http cache. But there is no code in the library to do that. So now my aim was to remove certain http request from that cache. For that I need to know what would be the key value. So that I can construct that and will remove that from the cachefactory of http list

Comment: They key is the request url including the parameters. You can read more about it here: [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) under Caching.